# Creating multiple buttons of the same class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create around 25 buttons of a class `ButtonControls`which inherit from normal `Button`class with nested `for` loops to create a square. I added special properties called `coordsX` and `coordsY` I use to know where they should be placed in a form and for some other use that's too complicated to explain here. When I create a button it's placed where it should be and write it's "coords" as it's text and it shows the right values, but when I click it, the messagebox should pop up and give me the coords of this button, but it always shows the coords of the last button created.

```
private void CreateBoard()
        {
            for (int x=0;x<BoardWidth;x++)
            {
                for (int y=0;y<BoardHeight;y++)
                {
                    ButtonControls bc = new ButtonControls(x,y,PieceSize);
                    //bc.Name = x+"_"+y;
                    //bc.BackgroundImage = PieceBmp;
                    //bc.Size = new Size(PieceSize,PieceSize);
                    bc.Click += PieceButton_Click;
                    Point docks = new Point(20, 20);
                    docks.Offset(ButtonControls.coordsX, ButtonControls.coordsY);
                    bc.Location = docks;
                    Controls.Add(bc);
                }
            }
        }
```

The constructor at use looks like this:

```
        public ButtonControls (int X,int Y, int ButtonSize)
        {
            coordsX = X*ButtonSize;
            coordsY = Y*ButtonSize;
            Name = X+"."+Y;
            BackColor = Color.White;
            Size = new Size(ButtonSize,ButtonSize);

            Font = new Font("Arial",6);
            Text = coordsX + "." + coordsY;
        }

        public static int coordsX { get; set; }
        public static int coordsY { get; set; }
```

And the click event like this:

```
private void PieceButton_Click (object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ButtonControls.coordsX+"/"+ButtonControls.coordsY);
        }
```

How can I make it show the coords of the button I clicked?

Comment: Use the `sender` parameter. Cast it to `ButtonControls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your coordinates are `static`.

Remove the `static` ie.

```
public int coordsX { get; set; }
public int coordsY { get; set; }
```

Then use the `sender` instance rather than the class to access these properties in the click event.

```
private void PieceButton_Click (object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     var button = (ButtonControls)sender;
     MessageBox.Show(button.coordsX+"/"+ button.coordsY);
}
```

As a side note, your class name `ButtonControls` is not great - why is it plural? `ButtonControl` is better but it still does not describe the difference from the class it inherits from... `PieceButton` is even better (I don't know the context so it is just a guess) but personally I would just call it `Piece`...

Answer (score 0):

Cast your sender to the `BottonControls` to get the button clicked

Then, to access your property `coordsX , coordsY,` you must remove `static` keyword

```
public int coordsX { get; set; }
public int coordsY { get; set; }

private void PieceButton_Click (object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     var button = (ButtonControls)sender;
     MessageBox.Show(button.coordsX+"/"+ button.coordsY);
}
```